# How can I make BarChart vertical in react-google-charts

Tags: reactjs, charts

I am using react-google-charts literary,
for my project i need to use vertical bars like chartType="BarChart".
the issue is that i need it to by vertical.

I tried to add "bars: 'vertical'" to options and everywhere I checked all the examples where building the chart without the component.
I what to use what I get from the react component.

this is the exsample that i am using.

https://react-google-charts.com/bar-chart#labeling-bars

```
<Chart
  width={'500px'}
  height={'300px'}
  chartType="BarChart"
  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
  data={[
    [
      'Element',
      'Density',
      { role: 'style' },
      {
        sourceColumn: 0,
        role: 'annotation',
        type: 'string',
        calc: 'stringify',
      },
    ],
    ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', null],
    ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver', null],
    ['Gold', 19.3, 'gold', null],
    ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2', null],
  ]}
  options={{
    title: 'Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    bar: { groupWidth: '95%' },
    legend: { position: 'none' },
  }}
/>
```

What am i missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `chartType="ColumnChart"` instead. [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvzy6xmm95?from-embed)

```js
<Chart
  width={'500px'}
  height={'300px'}
  chartType="ColumnChart"
  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
  data={[
    [
      'Element',
      'Density',
      { role: 'style' },
      {
        sourceColumn: 0,
        role: 'annotation',
        type: 'string',
        calc: 'stringify',
      },
    ],
    ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', null],
    ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver', null],
    ['Gold', 19.3, 'gold', null],
    ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2', null],
  ]}
  options={{
    title: 'Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    bar: { groupWidth: '95%' },
    legend: { position: 'none' },
  }}
/>
```

Comment: saw it, but i need each column to be in different color, I saw it only in BarChart.

Comment: @GilHadad updated answer with a working example. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: working thanks! 
The thing is that when i looked on column charts there were no examples only "Same as BarChart"